# How to add CSS/JS/an Image to a module backend

Tags: module, administrator

I have long wondered how to change my admin particularly for my custom modules.  For many cases using an XML file is fine and I can use the built-in Joomla! form fields.

In some cases, I'd like to style them, which I can do by adding classes and then adding the content to the template file.  Which is 99.9% of the time Isis.

But I have always wondered how I would achieve this on **any** admin template.  I would need to load a CSS or JS file somehow.  I could do this with an addScript declaration, but I do not have a PHP file to add this to.  I could use an Admin Plugin, but that doesn't seem like the right solution.

And finally, how would I add an image, or some HTML e.g. an explanation or instructions.  I can use the description panel on some occasions, but on others, it would make sense to be next to the field itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally do this in my extensions by creating a custom field:

**XML:**

```
<fieldset name="something" label="Something" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_xxx/fields">
    <field type="testfield" />
</fieldset>
```

**mod_xxx/fields/testfield.php:**

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

class JFormFieldTest extends Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField
{

    protected $type = 'Test';

    protected function getLabel()
    {
        return;
    }

    protected function getInput()
    {
        // Custom JS
        HTMLHelper::_('script', 'mod_xxx/custom.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);

        // Custom CSS
        HTMLHelper::_('stylesheet', 'mod_xxx/custom.css', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);

        // Custom HTML
        $html = '<p>Hello</p>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: And then you use the class to position it?  Seems like this may be a difficult thing to position if it's a custom field.  Or is it reasonably straight forward?

Comment: I found it interesting that you use `HTMLHelper` which I haven't encountered before and also `getInput` when I would have used https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript.  Is there any reason you decided to go this way?

Comment: Yesh use a class to position it. I used some Javascript myself aswell but you may not need to. `HTMLHelper` is just the namespaced version of `JHtml`...still works the same way. I just never use `addScript()`

Comment: And perhaps that documentation?  Would that be the right thing to do?

Comment: You mean the Joomla Documentation? You can if you like

Comment: O don't mind doing it so long as it's the right thing to do

Comment: I'm not too sure what's happening with the docs for PHP stuff, so I won't say go ahead and do it, just incase you end up wasting time.

Comment: It's not a waste of time because I use that doc to remind me how to do it. But also others will be doing the same. Even if it gets changed again, it won't take too long I'll just add it at the top.

Comment: does that mean HTMLHelper is the J4 way of doing things and we should try not to use JHTML anymore?

Comment: @Eoin, `HTMLHelper` is a namespaced version of `JHtml`. These namespaced classes were added in J4 and backported to J3. The original classes will be removed in J5 but will still work in J4,  so I would personally use the new approach which will save you time in the future.

Comment: I'm going to start a new question about this as I'm to fresh to work it all out

Comment: Ok I have now had time to try this, but when I do, I get a text field in the back end.  I don't get any JS loading and I don't get any CSS loading.  I search the source and the files aren't being loaded but browsing files show they exist.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sure can I've created a question: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28560/im-trying-to-make-a-custom-form-field-to-show-css-and-js-but-i-cant-get-it-wor