# How to use HTMLHelper to add to the document head

Tags: javascript, custom-component, custom-module, jinput, joomla-4.x

In this post: [How to add CSS/JS/an Image to a module backend](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24057/how-to-add-css-js-an-image-to-a-module-backend/24058?noredirect=1#comment32059_24058) @lodder shows me how to use `HTMLHelper` to add `CSS` and `JavaScript`.

Previously I had followed the Joomla! documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript which suggests using `addScript()`

In the example by Lodder he is using a `form field` and then is using `getInput` so I wondered if that makes a difference.  I'm keen to learn the right way to do things moving forwards and I know **namespacing** is what I should be using as a good habit.

My question is instead of using `JHhtml` for things like

`JHtml::script('jui/jquery.min.js', false, true);`

to load jQuery first, can I now do

`HTMLHelper::_('script', 'jui/jquery.min.js', false, true);`

And secondly, instead of adding to the document head like this:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript($mediaUrl . '/js/' . $moduleName . ".js",
  "text/javascript", true, false, array('version' => 'auto'));
```

Can I do it like this?

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->HTMLHelper::_('script', 'jui/jquery.min.js', false, true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `JHtml` is an alias for `Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper` class. You'll have to start using the real class sooner or later because the alias will not exist in Joomla! 5.0. To use the real class you have to either import it:

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

HTMLHelper::doSomething();
HTMLHelper::doSomethingElse();
```

Or use fully qualified class name:

```
\Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::doSomething();
\Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::doSomethingElse();
```

2) No, that doesn't work. The document object does not have property called `HTMLHelper`. Use one of the methods shown above.

Note, you can use `HTMLHelper::_('jquery.framework')` to add core jQuery.