# Joomla Custom module With Owl carousel

Tags: module, carousel

I need some advice on how to implement an OWL carousel with Joomla! native custom module. I have done some research already and I have tried several options including the add of the owl files to the media/jui folder, but for now the result is null.

The html part is a simple code

```
1
```

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Djamel, welcome to JSE! Please if you could share/include some code you already used and failed, you can insert code parts by [edit]ing your question and we can see better what the real problem is with including that carousel in your module. Does the module work without the carousel?

Answer (score 2):

What do you exactly mean with "Joomla! native custom module"? Joomla's Custom HTML module?

The OWL carousel I found on github uses some JavaScript(JS) + CSS, and some HTML tags with classes that you could put in your Joomla custom HTML module:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
</div>
```

The JS + CSS have to be loaded on the pages where you display the Joomla Custom Module. To load JS or CSS, you could use Joomla's

- Factory::getDocument like described here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page
- or use Joomla's HTMLHelper: [How to use HTMLHelper to add to the document head](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24767/how-to-use-htmlhelper-to-add-to-the-document-head)

For instance, you could load the JS + CSS via your front-end template. However it will be loaded on all other pages as well and might have a (small) negative impact on the performance of your website.

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for the guideline, I will go through the doc