# I'm trying to make a custom form field to show CSS and JS but I can't get it work

Tags: form-fields-types

I've copied the instructions here: [How to add CSS/JS/an Image to a module backend](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24057/how-to-add-css-js-an-image-to-a-module-backend/24058?noredirect=1#comment36941_24058)

modulename.xml

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/fields">
            ~
            <field
                    name="myjavascript"
                    type="myjavascript"
                    label="My Javascript"
                    description="JFIELD_TITLE_DESC"
            />
            ~
```

models/fields/fields.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<field
        name="myjavascript"
        type="myjavascript"
        label="JGLOBAL_TITLE"
        description="JFIELD_TITLE_DESC"
        required="true"
/>
```

models/forms/myjavascript.php

```
<?php

    // Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
    
    use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
    
    class JFormFieldMyjavascript extends Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField
    {
    
        protected $type = 'Myjavascript';
    
        protected function getLabel()
        {
            return;
        }
    
        protected function getInput()
        {
            // Custom JS
            HTMLHelper::_('script', 'media/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields_backend.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);
    
            // Custom CSS
            HTMLHelper::_('stylesheet', 'media/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields_backend.css', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);
    
            // Custom HTML
            $html = '<p>Hello, is it me you\'re waiting for</p>';
    
            return $html;
        }
    }
```

media/js/myjavascript.js

```
window.event("domready", function() {
    alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
});
```

media/css/myjavascript.css

```
.card-body h2 {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the path's correctly for the HTMLHelper calls. You're using `relative => true`, which means the `media` and `js/css` are not required in the path.

So you'll want to use:

```
// JS
HTMLHelper::_('script', 'mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields_backend.js', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);
    
// CSS
HTMLHelper::_('stylesheet', 'mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields_backend.css', ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]);
```

As for the actual Javascript, `window.event` will throw an error, so I'd suggest using:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    alert('The DOM has loaded')
})
```

#### Update:

You're setting the following path for your field:

```
addfieldpath="/modules/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/fields"
```

However the actual file resides in:

```
models/forms/myjavascript.php
```

so you need to add the file to the path you've defined for the `addfieldpath` attribute.

Comment: I'm still not seeing a difference in the backend.  Could it be because of where I'm saving the media files?

Comment: Where are they saved?

Comment: media/mod_modulename/css/modulename.css in the media folder in the module name

Comment: So `media/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields/css/mod_joomla4_module_custom_form_fields_backend.css`?

Comment: Do you at least see `Hello, is it me you're waiting for` being displayed on the page?

Comment: Nope, I do not.  What I see is my previous input, which was a text input that I was overriding.  Could it be admin cache?  I had been assuming text was the default if it didn't know what to do

Comment: @Eoin see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, updated my code.  Man something isn't right here.  Why is my old field showing?  I initially tried extending a hidden field.  So now I'm seeing a text field with the correct label.  I'm not getting any HTML, JS, or CSS.  Will the field you have shown me show up  as a text field?  Why is that still showing if not?

Comment: Could you zip everything up so I can test locally?

Comment: Sure, but how to reach you?  DM you on Facebook?

Comment: yeah that's fine